# Why the enum constants must be declared before any other variables and methods declaration in an enum type?

Tags: java, syntax, enums

If I declare a variable before or without declaring enum constants in this way:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    int i = 90;
}
```

It shows following compilation error.

```
MyEnum.java:3: <identifier> expected
{
 ^
MyEnum.java:4: ',', '}', or ';' expected
        int i = 90;
        ^
MyEnum.java:4: '}' expected
        int i = 90;
             ^
MyEnum.java:5: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
4 errors
```

But if I declare an enum constant before declaring `i` then it compiles fine. 
Even the following code will compile fine:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    ;//put a semicolon
    int i = 90;
}
```

Why java enum is designed in this way?

Comment: First and foremost, `enum` is designed to be an *enumeration* of more than zero elements. This design is perfectly valid.

Comment: Because it is mandatory to have at least one enum constant. Because that's the way the syntax is defined in the Java Language Specification. Because.

Comment: @EJP But in later case I haven't declared any enum constant but have simply appended a semicolon before declaring a variable. Is'nt it going against the mandate that an `Enum` should have at least one enum constant?

Comment: That means there are no enum constants. The compiler needs a way of knowing where the enum constants stop and the other stuff starts. That's the way the language designers chose.

Comment: @EJP Thanks.That's what I wanted to know...It is pure language designers choice..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `;` indicates the end of the enum identifiers list.  Apparently you can have an empty enum list, but you must have one.

See [8.9.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1) of the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf):

> 8.9.1 Enum Constants
>   The body of an enum type may contain enum constants

Comment: In particular: `EnumBodyDeclarations:
    ; ClassBodyDeclarationsopt`

Comment: Thnx for the quick response and the relevant link to JLS. Yeah I went through that link . But I could not get a reason for such desgin constraint for enums in java. So, finally it should be assumed that It is only the way java has choosed to design enums ? There is no other reasons like : the way enums is treated by JVM in terms of loading , initialization or any other...

Answer (score 2):

Two mandatory parts of enum is:

1. enum identifiers;
2. enum body.

You have to first declare **enum identifiers** list before **enum body**.
Here, `;` is showing the first part, as the first part is mandatory. If you ignore that, it will produce an compilation error. If you add `;` then it will compile as you **fulfill both the criteria**.