# End of list of enums in Java

Tags: java, syntax, enums

I have a code block as follows :

1. ```
   public enum TierEnum {
       Express,
       Standard; // the semi-colon is redundant
   }
   ```

Well in the code semi-colon(`;`) is marked as redundant by the compiler. At the same time if I use

2. ```
   public enum TierEnum {
       Express,
       Standard 
   }; // again the semi-colon is redundant
   ```

Why in both the cases is the semi-colon marked redundant? How do I define the end of the list of enums in Java?

Comment: You don't. That's why the compiler is warning you.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338246/why-the-enum-constants-must-be-declared-before-any-other-variables-and-methods-d

Comment: Do you write inner classes as `class Foo { ... };` as well?

Comment: [Why is the semicolon ; not required but allowed at the end of a class definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614393/why-is-the-semicolon-not-required-but-allowed-at-the-end-of-a-class-definition)

Comment: You're asking 2 questions in one also. One of them is a duplicate of that ^

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The terminating semicolon is needed if you add some code to the enum, like:

```
public enum TierEnum
{
    Express( "Exp"),
    Standard( "Std");

    private String abbr;

    private TierEnum( String aAbbr )
    {
        abbr = aAbbr;
    }


    public String getAbbr()
    {
        return abbr;
    }
}
```